# libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to run a git found here: https://github.com/fadymedhat/TMIXT

A bin file is being called imgtxtenh which I guess was compiled from https://github.com/mauvilsa/imgtxtenh

When executed with this line:

```
$PRINT_PARENT_DIR/bin/imgtxtenh -u mm -d 118.1102362205 $TEMP_IMAGE $TEMP_IMAGE;
```

I am getting this error:

```
/home/user/TMIXT/RecognitionPrinted/bin/imgtxtenh: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I tried `locate libMagickCore`

I got:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3.0.0
```

Could it be because my machine does not have so.2? If so how I can solve this?

Comment: You could try temporarily making a symlink and see if you can get away with using the new version... `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.{3,2}` It's not very professional and may crash, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: It did work but I would like more feedback on how it can be solved the proper way :)

Comment: I got the same error, when upgrading my ubuntu distribution, with rails after an gem install rmagick -v 2.15.4 it worked again.